# ASP.NET/MVC with HTML 5 local storage key/value pair

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html, local-storage, key-value

We are developing several asp.net MVC applications that need to exist in both a connected/disconnected state.

Out of the several connection strategies available (Google Gears, Microsoft Sync, etc) we decided on HTML 5 w/ local storage utilizing javascript key/value pair.  Ensuring the disconnected state is functional in Internet Explorer is a high priority.

Does anyone know of resources available online or otherwise to help us in this endevour?

For example, one excellent resource we have found
http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2011/01/12/asp-net-and-html5-local-storage.aspx

Comment: In a rather interesting twist, IE is the best browser for offline storage. It's had it's own proprietary implementation of this since IE5.

Comment: It seems like the main issue with implementing asp.net MVC and supporting HTML 5 local storage - how does routing work in a disconnected state?  In a disconnected mode using only key/values, only html/javascript can be run on the client end.

Answer (score 3):

This was the best resource for me: http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/storage.html on the topic.